# How to Write following equation using amsmath in Latex

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, math-operators

Equations need in Latex format. These are the equations

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please shown what you tried so far to get the equations. What exactly is the problematic part for you?

Comment: `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{align}\begin{document}\begin{align} xxx & = yyy\\ uuu& = vvvv\end{align}\end{document}` as starting point. You now only need to insert your math expressions.

Comment: Should the individual equations each be centered on their respective lines, or should they be aligned on the `=` symbols? Do the equation numbers have to have staggered offsets from the right-hand margin, or is it ok to align them all along the margin?

Comment: Also, what is the `3` in the equation nubers? A section number, or a main equation number, these equations being subequations?

Comment: Yes each equation should be centered on their respective line. 3 is section number.

Comment: @Zarko: how is your suggested duplicate related to this question?

Comment: @leandriis, ups. i miss the question. My comment is related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/575651/problem-with-footnote-placement-in-beamer. I will delete it here ASAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath} % used for cases environment only

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
        I_{i,j}=\frac{(I_{i,j}-\bar{I}_i)}{\sigma_i}
    \end{equation}
    
    \begin{equation}
        I_{input}=X_{i,j}
    \end{equation}
    
    \begin{equation}
        O_{inception}=concatenate(L_A,L_B,L_C,L_D)
    \end{equation}

    \begin{equation}
        \sigma(X_i)=\frac{e^{Z_i}}{\Sigma_{j=1}^{K=2}e^{Z_j}}
    \end{equation}

    \begin{equation}
        O(X_{i,j})=
        \begin{cases}
            1, & X_{i,j}^1 > X_{i,j}^0 \\
            0, & otherwise
        \end{cases}
    \end{equation}

    \begin{equation}
        Recog.=\frac{TP+TN}{TP+TN+FP+FN}
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Resulting in the following:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me what should i do so that the equations comes in center of page?

Comment: You can left align each of these equations by replacing equation with falign and adding && after each equation. Like so:
\begin{flalign}
    I_{i,j}=\frac{(I_{i,j}-\bar{I}_i)}{\sigma_i}&&
\end{flalign}
If your question is answered, please consider marking this solution as the accepted answer.

Comment: I tried but its not working. can you show it for one equation?

Comment: I read left aligned before. The equations should be centered by default, maybe post a new question explaining your alignment problem better?

Comment: Indices and text, which are not variables, as this case are *input*,  *inception*, *concatenate*, and *otherwise* had to by typed as `\math{input}`, etc or eventually as `\mathit{input}`.  You propose bad typography (at least), sorry.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/575678/kindly-help-to-write-the-equations-in-amsmath-latex?noredirect=1#comment1449658_575678

Comment: Kindly read this post. I have new question. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/575714/how-to-write-the-following-equation-in-amsmath-in-latex-the-equation-should-be