# Problem with footnote placement in beamer

Tags: beamer, footnotes

I am using the `beamer` class for my presentation. My problem is the placements of footnotes. Unfortunately, all footnotes appear at the end (the last slide of the presentation). How do I get footnotes to appear on the slide I used them?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{}
This is\footnote{The first Footnote} a test.\\
This is\footnote{The second Footnote} a test.\\
This is a test.\\
This is a test.\\
\framebreak
This is a test.\\
\framebreak
This is\footnote{The first Footnote} a test.\\
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have edited the question. The codes were added.

Comment: Thanks. I've eliminated all packages as they were irrelevant. The `beamer` manual specifically warns about this side effect of the option `allowframebreaks`. Do you *really* need it?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Yes, I need seriously to "\allowframebreaks". I cannot remove this option.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, the question is the same, but the answer does not solve my problem.

Comment: Since you explicitly used `\framebreak` in your MWE anyways, why not simply go for three individual `frame` environments? The `beamer` manual also explicitly warns: "The use of this option is evil. In a (good) presentation you prepare each slide carefully and think twice before putting something on a certain slide rather than on some different slide.  Using the `allowframebreaks`option invites the creation of horrible, endless presentations that resemble more a “paper projected on the wall” than a presentation."

Answer (score -1):

I found a shortcut:

After creating all the slides with Latex, separate the pages that contain the footnote from the whole text (let them form a separate frame). For example, run the following codes.

Just note that in this way, if you have inserted `\framebreak`-code manually in some places, then you must put `\\` (or an empty line) before all the `\framebreak`-codes, otherwise, Latex combines some pages :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Title}
\date{2021}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{}
\maketitle
\framebreak
This is the first page.\\
\framebreak
This is the second page.\\
\framebreak
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
This is\footnote{The first Footnote} a test.\\
This is\footnote{The second Footnote} a test.\\
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{}
This is a test.\\
This is a test.\\
\framebreak
This is a test.
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
This is\footnote{The third Footnote} a test.\\
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```